# I modified 1 variable, but 2 changed

Tags: c#

I was writing my code, I thought all was good and then I tested my code.
In the code I'am changing the value:

```
ennemy.object_infos[0] = "Ennemy";
player.object_infos[0] = "Player";
```

And the output of

```
 Console.WriteLine(player.object_infos[0])
```

was "Ennemy" and the output of

```
Console.WriteLine(ennemi.object_infos[0])
```

was "Ennemy"

Exactly the code was :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        GameEngine game = new GameEngine();
        GameEngine.GameObject ennemy = new GameEngine.GameObject(); 
        GameEngine.GameObject player = new GameEngine.GameObject(); 
        ennemy.object_infos = GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default;
        player.object_infos = GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default;
        ennemy.object_infos[0] = "Ennemy";
        player.object_infos[0] = "Player";
        Console.WriteLine(ennemy.object_infos[0] + "," + player.object_infos[0]);
    }
}
public class GameEngine 
{
    public List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
    /*
    Vector2 : vector with 2 values x,y
    */
    public struct Vector2 
    {
        public float x,y;
        public Vector2(float xaxis,float yaxis)
        {
            x = xaxis;
            y = yaxis;
        }
    }
    public class GameObject 
    {
        /* 
        object_infos indexes:
        0 = name(string),
        1 = id(double),
        2 = sprite path in assets(string),
        3 = transform (array of 3 vectors2)
        4 = rectangle collider(Vector2 size w,h)
        5 = isActive(bool)
        6 = isVisible(bool)
        7 = tag
        */
        public object[] object_infos;
        /*
        transform default :
        index 0 = position,
        index 1 = rotation,
        index 2 = scale
        */
        private static Vector2[] transform_default = {new Vector2(0,0),new Vector2(0,0),new Vector2(1,1)};
        /*
        On new object creation apply this object infos
        */
        public static object[] object_infos_default = {"New Object", 0, "/Assets/default.png", transform_default, new Vector2(1,1), true, true, "object"};
    }
    /*
    engine class for all mathematics
    */
    public class Math
    {
        /*
        public static bool areColliding(Vector2 first_object_pos, Vector2 first_object_collidersize,Vector2 second_object_pos, Vector2 second_object_collidersize) 
        {

        }
        */
    }
}
```

Its really strange i changed one value and two changed please someone help me!

Comment: Getting a message that your post is too short does not mean you should spam text to bypass the message

Comment: sorry no idea what write

Comment: Also you make both `ennemy.object_infos` and `player.object_infos` reference `GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default` so why are you surprised that changes affect both? They all reference the same array

Comment: You're assigning the same instance of `GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default` to both objects, so of course modifying one will modify the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ennemy.object_infos = GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default;
player.object_infos = GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default;
```

This assigns `object_infos_default` to *both* `ennemy.object_infos` and `player.object_infos`. Due to the way assignments work, you are assigning just a reference to that object array. So both `object_infos` refer to the *same object*, which is also the same object that `object_infos_default` refers to.

So when you change the object through either of the three variables, you are changing it for all of them.

You should create a copy instead, for example using `Array.clone`:

```
ennemy.object_infos = (object[])GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default.Clone();
player.object_infos = (object[])GameEngine.GameObject.object_infos_default.Clone();
```

Comment: People forget that `static` means there is only one reference for ALL instances of an object.

Answer (score 0):

That's not strange, your ennemy.object_infos and player.object_infos are the same object, and thus point to the same location in memory.  Thus when you change one it'll change the other.

You'll need to instead create a new object for each if you don't want this to occur.